# How do I sync Vagrant sync folder with VirtualBox and CentOS/Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, centos, sync, vagrant

I can't get the /vagrant folder to synchronize. It will synchronize from Windows host to CentOS guest, but only if I manually run `vagrant rsync` or `vagrant up`, and will delete any new files in the guest. It won't sync from guest to host.

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Wed Mar 15 21:00:00 2017 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cd /vagrant
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ ls
Vagrantfile  vagrant.log
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ touch tmp.txt
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ ls
tmp.txt  Vagrantfile  vagrant.log
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Chloe@xps /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/Documents/server
$ ls
vagrant.log  Vagrantfile
```

I tried to manually mount and it gave an error

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
```

I tried to manually set a shared folder in VirtualBox interface and restarted

[image: virtual box shared folder settings dialog]

It doesn't give any errors on `vagrant up` and there is nothing in the [debug log](https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/7c11e30934241f02e8cac54fd615da03).

Version 5.1.16 r113841 (Qt5.6.2)
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the name (1st column) of `/vagrant` in VirtualBox to `vagrant` and manually running this command inside the guest:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ touch /vagrant/tmp.txt
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ exit
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Chloe@xps /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/Documents/server
$ ls
tmp.txt  vagrant.log  Vagrantfile
```

Not even selecting 'Auto mount' checkbox will mount it automatically. By the way, 1000 is the uid and gid of `vagrant` user. `id -u vagrant; id -g vagrant`

You can add this to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
        mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant
  SHELL
```

Comment: Successfully used your solution, thanks for sharing it ! (tried many other proposal, none worked for me). After installing 3 ubuntu and 2 debian boxes, I noticed that ubuntu boxes are ok : hashicorp/precise64, ubuntu/trusty64 and ubuntu/xenial64 didn't show the problem, but debian aren't ok : debian/(jessie64|stretch64) demonstrated the same problem and needed your fix. In case someone wants to try to reproduce, host OS is Windows 10, with VirtualBox 5.2.2, guest additions + vagrant-vbguest plugin installed. Did you find info about the cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you update to Virtualbox to version 5.1.18 which solves that problem!

Comment: Oh wow they just released it today. Just got the notice popup. Doesn't Oracle have regression tests so they stop breaking things?

Comment: That still doesn't work. I upgraded to 'Version 5.1.18 r114002 (Qt5.6.2)', removed the manual mount provision lines in my answer, started the box, touched `/vagrant/tmp.txt`, and the file still did not appear in my host folder.